# Map enum to subclass type in Typescript

Tags: typescript, enums, redux

I'm using Typescript and Redux. Is there a way to ensure typing of the `action` parameter of a reducer based on the `type`? This would be similar to the Entity Framework mapping an enum column to an appropriate subclass.

Here's an incomplete example:

```
enum ActionType {
  doThing1,
  doThing2      
}

interface Action {
  readonly type: ActionType
}

interface Thing1Action extends Action {
   readonly payload: Thing1Payload;
}

interface Thing2Action extends Action {
   readonly payload: Thing2Payload;
}


interface State {
   readonly thing1: Thing1Payload;
   readonly thing2: Think2Payload;
}

const initialState: State = {
   thing1: null,
   thing2: null,
}

function reducer(state = initialState, action: Action): State {
    switch (action.type)
    {
        case ActionType.doThing1: 
            return {...state, thing1: action.payload };
    }
    return state;
}
```

in the example above, I'd like to constrain the `action.payload` to represent a `Thing1Payload`. Right now, Typescript will complain that `action` does not have `payload` or when I omit the type for `action`, it gives me `any` for it all.

I'd only prefer it at code and compile time checking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is called a [tagged union](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2016/11/03/typescript-2-0-tagged-union-types). In each interface that inherits from  `Action` you have to redefine  the `type` field, but you type it with the appropriate enum literal type ( basically specifying a single possible enum value as the type of the field).

Then you define a union type with all the derived interfaces, and use it as the parameter type. The switch over `type` will then act as a type guard.

```
enum ActionType {
    doThing1,
    doThing2
}

interface Action {
    readonly type: ActionType
}
interface Thing1Payload {
    b: number
}

interface Thing2Payload {
    a: number
}
interface Thing1Action extends Action {
    readonly type: ActionType.doThing1 // redefine the filed, only value assignable is ActionType.doThing1
    readonly payload: Thing1Payload;
}

interface Thing2Action extends Action {
    readonly type: ActionType.doThing2 // redefine the filed, only value assignable is ActionType.doThing2
    readonly payload: Thing2Payload;
}


interface State {
    readonly thing1: Thing1Payload;
    readonly thing2: Thing2Payload;
}

const initialState: State = {
    thing1: <Thing1Payload>null,
    thing2: <Thing2Payload>null,
}
// Interface with all actions
type AllAction = Thing1Action | Thing2Action;

function reducer(state = initialState, action: AllAction): State {
     // This switch will now be a type guard
    switch (action.type) {
        case ActionType.doThing1:
            // action will be of typed Thing1Action
            return { ...state, thing1: action.payload };
        case ActionType.doThing2:
            // action will be of typed Thing2Action
            return { ...state, thing2: action.payload };
    }
    return state;
}
```